# Where to find apk build using apportable

Tags: apportable

So, I have made the tweejump iOS application successfully for android using apportable. And apportable also installed the application on the devices. But the mysterious thing is, I am not able to find the tweejump-debug.apk in the tweejump folder.

Also, I am using the free sdk.

Please suggest.

-Nimit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apportable builds are stored separately from the project itself - in $HOME/.apportable/SDK/build.

For example, to see the .apk files for the Spin example:

```
$ cd $HOME/.apportable/SDK/build
$ find . | grep "debug.apk$"
./android-armeabi-debug/Spin/Spin-debug.apk
```